# Ajax load data on scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How would one go about creating a function that loads data dynamically via ajax like Facebook or Twitter does?

Ive already written a function based off of the research i've done but it doesn't seem to work so im willing to hear how you have done it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    var pagenumber = document.getElementById("pagenumber");
    var results_box = document.getElementById("results_box");
    var combo= pagenumber.innerHTML.split("|");
    var pn = parseInt(combo[0]);
    var last= parseInt(combo[1]);     
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {               
       // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
        results_box.innerHTML="Loading...";
         if(last != 1){
            if (pn < last) { 
            request_page(pn+1);
            }               
            else if(pn==last){ 
            pagenumber.innerHTML = pn+1 +"|"+last; 
            request_page(last);                                                 
            }
            else{
            results_box.innerHTML="No More Content available";
            }
        }
     }
   });
});
```

This function doesn't show any issue in the console but it either doesn't fire or it loads multiple pages at once. All input is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When I have done infinite scrolling, I trigger the script when the scroll is within 10% of the bottom edge rather than an exact equality as you have it. This helps trigger the function in a more reliable way. You can prevent multiple loads at once by setting a variable on the DOM when an ajax call begins and resetting it when it is over. I have applied these ideas to the code below. Hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        var pagenumber = document.getElementById("pagenumber");
        var results_box = document.getElementById("results_box");
        var combo = pagenumber.innerHTML.split("|");
        var pn = parseInt(combo[0]);
        var last = parseInt(combo[1]);     
        if ($(document).hasClass("idle") && ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.9)) {               
            //ajax call get data from server and append to the div
            //when request begins ("beforeSend"), $(document).toggleClass("idle");
            results_box.innerHTML = "Loading...";
            if (last != 1) {
                if (pn < last) { 
                    request_page(pn+1);
                } else if (pn == last) { 
                    pagenumber.innerHTML = pn + 1 + "|" +last; 
                    request_page(last);                                                 
                } else {
                    results_box.innerHTML = "No More Content available";
                }
            }
            $(document).toggleClass("idle");
        }
    });
});
```